# Set value for joined table in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a razor page for a windows auth MVC app that tracks who created the record. The basic idea looks like this:

```
public class User {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string NetworkId {get;set;}
}

public class Event {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}

    public DateTime Created {get;set;}

    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

On the Razor page, I'm trying to create a `HiddenFor` for to set the user ID , but I can't get it to post correctly. Setting the `Created` field works correctly (`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created, new { Value = DateTime.Now })`), but the `UserId` won't set.

This doesn't work:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.NetworkId, new { Value = User.Identity.Name })
```

This throws a null reference exception:

```
    @{
        Model.User.NetworkId = User.Identity.Name;
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.NetworkId)
```

There has to be an easier way to do this, other than looking for the NetworkId on the table and pulling back the actual primary key.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that your `User.Identity` is not null? Also it's not good to set values like this, but if you want to do it you should escape `Value` like this `new { @value = User.Identity.Name }`

Comment: It's not null. I can pass it as a string field to the Event model (which is the model of the Razor page). But trying to pass it to the User property isn't working.

Comment: Ah, i get it. how you pass model to your View? I bet `Model.User` - is `null` that's why you get your exception. Show your controller.

Comment: The controller was my issue! I was pulling the User object, and not the User.Id, so I could attach that to the Event object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101909/discussion-between-teo-van-kot-and-dan-champagne).